# Removal of the distinction between the "initial condition" and the "laws of physics"?

Tags: philosophy-of-physics

### Background and Question

Here's something I was wondering: The (known) laws of physics can be formulated in such a way that one say: "initial condition" + "laws of physics" gives us a "final solution." I am thinking of something along the lines of an [initial value problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial_value_problem) (if the law is a partial differential equation) or [Born rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Born_rule) (where the "final solution" is not unique).

My question is this is there any line of argument in philosophy which argues for the removal of the distinction between the "initial condition" and the "laws of physics."

An argument effectively doing this by saying the space (Venn diagram) of initial values is a point. If any other other values are inserted then the law breaks down (we get an unacceptable solution for example: divergent solutions)

P.S: I have a degree in physics not in philosophy. I hope this is an acceptable question?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Philosophy SE. Yes, this is the kind of well articulated, motivated and specific question that we are looking for. See  [Laws and Initial Conditions by Frisch](http://faculty.philosophy.umd.edu/mfrisch/paper/laws_and_ic.pdf):"*I discuss two case studies from classical electrodynamics challenging the distinction
between laws that delineate physically possible words and initial conditions*".

Comment: @Conifold  Your link gave a 404 error.I googled the quoted words and found the paper.  Yes, this is what I was looking for. Here's the link I used: https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/bf43/591d38aaa5f2a28e0c44779fcda2e17d961e.pdf

Comment: Lee Smolin in his musing about temporality argues that in cosmology the distinction does not make sense, e.g.*the absolute separation of laws and initial conditions, and thus of laws and states, is tied to the empirical context of studying small subsystems  of the universe*. He is certainly not the first but a quick look at his views might be of interest; the book or at least https://www.bu.edu/cphs/files/2013/01/Lee-Smolin-Time-and-Law-in-Cosmology-10.18.13.pdf

Comment: General relativity is a theory that in its most general form isn't really about taking initial conditions and evolving them forward, as seen for example by the fact that you can have spacetimes that respect the field equations but involve [closed timelike curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_timelike_curve). If you think of the mathematical space of all possible [Lorentzian manifolds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-Riemannian_manifold) with matter/energy fields defined on them, the equations just pick out a subset which respect the field equations at all points.

Comment: @Hypnosifl I don't think that is true. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial_value_formulation_(general_relativity) . It is simply a very difficult initial value problem.

Comment: @MoreAnonymous — that’s why I said “in its most general form”, that page is about how it’s possible to mathematically reformulate general relativity in terms of initial conditions and deterministic dynamical laws, but this can only be done for a certain subset of the spacetimes permitted by the more general form. In particular my understanding is that the initial value formulation is usually restricted to “globally hyperbolic” spacetimes, though a footnote on p. 3 of [this paper](http://philsci-archive.pitt.edu/15067/1/CounterfactualsinGR_final_v3.pdf) says it can work for some other types.

Comment: Are you asking about [determinism vs. indeterminism](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/55463/2014)?

Comment: @Geremia I was asking: Given there exists the law(s) that govern the time evolution of a system (say the universe). Are there any adherents who argue such law of this system can only handle effectively one initial condition (an observable universe of being of point size). I'm not sure what - the doctrine of "tychism, anancism, and agapism" - would have to say about this?

Comment: @Conifold would you like to answer this post so I can accept your answer?

Comment: "the set of initial values is a point" reminds me of the Big Bang. physics basically asserts that the big bang was a "uniform point" of spacetime. my other answer is, **fractals** which can seem to yield arbitrary complexity even from "primitive" or "nearly nonexistent" initial conditions. an example/ mini case study/ toy problem is (reverse) "trajectories" arising in the collatz problem all originating from a single value, 1. the collatz problem has many properties evocative of physics eg density, "trajectories" etc...

Comment: This seems the right course of action, si! Remove the distinction between an apple and an apple.

Comment: Frisch's paper can be found here https://faculty.philosophy.umd.edu/mfrisch/papers/laws_and_ic.pdf. Also of interest https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11229-016-1203-0, https://dergipark.org.tr/tr/download/article-file/694714

Answer (score 4):

There is indeed a line of argument in philosophy that aims to blur the distinction between initial conditions and the laws of physics. This view is called the "best system analysis" (BSA) of laws of nature, and it is associated with philosophers such as David Lewis and Bas van Fraassen.

The BSA is rooted in the Humean approach to laws of nature, which claims that laws are just regularities or patterns in the world, rather than entities that govern or cause events. According to the BSA, the laws of physics are those that comprise the best system – that is, the system that best balances simplicity, strength, and fit to the actual world.

In this view, the initial conditions are part of the description of the world, and the laws are derived from the best systematization of these descriptions. In other words, there's no fundamental distinction between initial conditions and laws, since the laws are an emergent product of the overall pattern of the world's initial conditions and subsequent events.

By integrating initial conditions into the best system, the BSA approach to some extent eliminates the need for a sharp distinction between initial conditions and laws of physics. However, this view does not go as far as to say that the space of initial values is a single point or that any other values would necessarily lead to a breakdown of the laws.

Answer (score 2):

This is largely an argument at cross purposes. Take Newton's laws of motion. Clearly there is a sense in which a clear distinction can be drawn between the laws applying to a system and the initial conditions uniquely associated with the system. I can take ten different physical systems, each with their own unique initial conditions- they will all evolve into different states, but all do so in accordance with Newton's laws. There I am using the term 'initial conditions' specifically to refer to the dispositions of the individual elements of a system at some time t which I take to be the start of a period of particular interest. Now, if you want to lump into that definition of 'initial conditions' the fact that the objects obey Newton's laws then you are simply using the term 'initial conditions' in a different way, and moreover a way that blurs a useful distinction.

Comment: The laws of physics are clearly not a part of the initial conditions. The laws only describe the relation between the initial state and the subsequent states.

Comment: @PerttiRuismäki Hear hear- you make the point more succinctly than I did!

Comment: One can equally say that for each initial condition (ie each distnct system) a different law applies (boundary conditions+Newton's law) which has only some similarities to the laws applicable to other systems (ie abstracting Newton' laws for example).

Comment: @NikosM. You could, but you would be obscuring rather than illuminating the underlying commonality.

Comment: @MarcoOcram the issue here is how much commonality should we accept or expect. So personally I don't take this as a serious objection.

Comment: @NikosM. whatever floats your boat. And therein lies one of the joys of philosophy- the fact that through idiosyncratic usage the meaning of terms becomes so broadened that the scope for arguments at cross purposes becomes virtually endless.

Comment: @MarcoOcram I would not call this view peculiar or idiosyncratic. First of all the boundary conditions play a major role in defining a system and its dynamics, which can indeed result in qualitatively different systems and outcomes. Chaotic systems being prime examples. So taking into account boundary conditons in this sense, prevents us from making simplistic assumptions of similarity.

Comment: @NikosM. You said that one could equally argue that a different 'law' applies to every system, if you define 'law' to mean the combination of the boundary conditions plus the laws that are independent of those boundary conditions. I am simply saying that defining 'law' in that way is confusing the terminology with the usual definition.

Comment: @MarcoOcram of course, we are re-defining the term "law" in this case. I am simply arguing that it might be better if we do re-define it that way.

Comment: @NikosM. IVery well. Perhaps you might post a question about the suggestion, as it would be interesting to see a range of views about it

Comment: @marcoocram this question is exactly that. And it is nice to see different points of view on this.